# Bigquery: How to subscribe event

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wondering if there is a way to listen for bigquery events like when a new row is inserted to a table in which case I would get the raw data of the row. I'm trying to build a pipeline to subscribe bigquery events and filter only the insertions and send the row data to a queuing system like RabbitMQ

Comment: Google cloud Eventrc https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/overview                                              should be the right service to meet your requirement. See for bigquery events trigger on google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1beta2.BigQueryWrite.AppendRows on selected table you want to monitor insertions only. for more details here are all event triggers
https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#bigquery

Comment: Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison#broader_event_coverage_and_cloudevents_support) will help you ?